# Symfony framework - load Cyrillic data into database from fixtures

Tags: symfony1, character-encoding, fixtures

How can I load data into database from fixture files with Cyrillic data?

I've tried, but data in database is converted to ??? symbols. My fixture file is saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using MySQL? You may need to change the collation and/or character sets for the tables in your database.

A [whole section exists in the MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/globalization.html) on this topic which I recommend if your project scope for internationalisation is wide, but essentially applying this SQL to each table will help you:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Make sure your fixtures files are encoded using UTF-8, that your DB is using utf8_general_ci, and that your HTML pages specify that they're using utf-8 as charset too.