# when inserting cyrillic values into MySQL db values they appear to be "?????"

Tags: mysql, ado.net, character-encoding

I am using ado.net and MySQL db. When I insert cyrillic values into db, they are inserted as '?' symbols. I have tried various encodings in db, this didn`t help. I tried utf-8, utf-16, cp-1251 and many others.
So when I execute this code

```
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection con = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=root;database=voteme");
        MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO districts(DistrictName) VALUES('іавп')",con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

I receive '????' stored in my db. How do I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Edit: I tried to use both varchar and text field types in database: result was still the same.

Comment: I am using [Windows XP](http://imgur.com/seslv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Be sure to use UTF8 as database collation.
2. Try this immediately after opening connection:

   > con.ConnectionString = "database=DATABASE;server=localhost;user id=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD;CharSet=utf8"; after creating connection.

Comment: @steavy Same as you execute any other query.

Comment: Try the same with 'cp1251' instead of 'utf-8'

Comment: by the way, when I used 'utf-8', I received an exception that it is unknown encoding. So I tried 'utf8' and this, as I have already said, didn`t help

Comment: Are you sure, that your database uses correct charset? Try to alter table, as @Fish Biscuit told.

Comment: [screen1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1KzSi.jpg)    [screen2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SvtB6.jpg)

Comment: Try con.ConnectionString = "database=DATABASE;server=localhost;user id=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD;CharSet=utf8"; after creating connection.

Comment: this helped. Thanks. But where is the mistake at all? Originally I use Entity Framework and there is the same problem. And I am not really able to change connection strings.

Comment: No mistakes, just omission. :) If my answer helped, I'd appreciate question acceptance.

Comment: I voted up the comment. But how do I fix this omission, when I have no access to connection string(it is generated by Entity Framework) =\

Comment: edit your answer(not a comment) using this: "database=DATABASE;server=localhost;user id=USERNAME;pwd=PASSWORD;CharSet=utf8"; and I`ll accept answer

Answer (score 0):

as per [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419296/924071) you might need to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: you should also use a NVARCHAR

Comment: there is no such thing as nvarchar in MySql as I see

Comment: maybe since you are using text the encoding is not applying, try using **VARCHAR** since it is stored in the table instead of text which is not (its a reference)

Comment: Edit: I tried to use both varchar and text field types in database: result was still the same.