# Symfony 1.4 can't insert cyrillic in the database

Tags: doctrine, symfony1, symfony-1.4, cyrillic

I'm working on a Symfony 1.4 (Doctrine) project with 2 language support (English and Bulgarian). From the backend I am able to add categories with titles on Bulgarian and English. Everything is fine until I try to add a title with Cyrillic letters. When I look into my database I see that the titles with Cyrillic letters are recorded as ???. I've already apllied `ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` to all tables but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Similar to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418098/symfony-framework-load-cyrillic-data-into-database-from-fixtures](this question)?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418098/symfony-framework-load-cyrillic-data-into-database-from-fixtures)?

Comment: Yes, same problem here, but I already fix it. If someone has the same situation just follow  this [link][1] 


  [1]: http://kosalads.blogspot.com/2013/03/mysql-55-how-to-change-mysql-default.html